# TFS Automated Build Output Folder Permissions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, tfs, tfsbuild

I have TFS 2010 automated builds setup and using a CopyDirectory activity to copy the latest build to our DEV site. This all works fine.

In our web app we use a App_Temp folder for user uploads/downloads. This folder needs write permissions on the web server for all users.

Is it possible to:
A) change permissions on the folder when it is copied, or
B) exclude this folder from being overwritten/deleted and recreated

I'm open to other solutions to this problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Personally, i'd have it set up as a virtual directory and place the physical folder outside of the sites root.  that way it doesn't exist in the physical folder hierarchy of the site to be deleted/recreated.  you can set the folder in the solution to not copy then

Comment: I was thinking of this too. My team and I have decided to upgrade to TFS 2012 very soon where this will be overcome with features not available in 2010. I'll pose this idea to the team anyway.